# Replace All matching string only at start

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace all matching occurrences at start of the string.
Here is a use case.
`www.example.com/example.com/http://example.com/www.abc.com/www.example.com/xyz.com/example.com`
should become
`www.abc.com/www.example.com/xyz.com/example.com`

every matching occurrence should be removed until a non matching string encounters.

I am using `preg_replace` currently I have this regular expression

`'/(http:\/\/){0,1}(www.){0,1}example.com(\/)*/i'`
The problem is that it replaces all matching strings.

I want to replace matched strings only at the start, if matching fails once after that it should not replace any thing.
Any helping suggestions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also capture the string instead of preg_replace:

```
(?:(?:www.|http::?\/\/)?example\.com\/)+(.*)
```

The only capture group contains the string you're looking for. See [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/yB2wN0).

Also, I noticed you had `http::` in your input string. I matched it with same in the regex but with a `?` just in case. And last thing, `{0,1}` might be written as `?`. It's shorter :)

The PHP code (I'm not too familiar with the language, but I believe this should work):

```
preg_match('/(?:(?:www.|http::?\/\/)?example\.com\/)+(.*)/', $html, $matches);
$url = $matches[1];
```

Comment: This uses `preg_match` by the way. But you can still use a `preg_replace` and replace by `\1`.

Comment: @Arif I'm not too familiar with PHP, but I believe that this should work: `preg_match('/(?:(?:www.|http::?\/\/)?example\.com\/)+(.*)/', $html, $matches);
$url = $matches[1];`

Comment: thanks. It helped me a lot. double colon in `http::` was just mistype.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `^` anchor to ensure it only matches at the beginning of the string:

```
'/^(http:\/\/){0,1}(www.){0,1}example.com(\/)*/i'
```

To learn more about anchors, check out [this regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

*Note:* In regular expressions, `?` is the same as `{0,1}`.

Comment: SOrry. replacing only first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

First of all PHP regex engine allows you to use an alternate regex delimiter. So you can use `~` or `#` instead and void escaping forward slashes. Also dot needs to be escaped since its a special regex character.

A refactored regex can be like this:

```
'~(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?example\.com/~i'
```

Complete PHP code:

```
$regex_replace = '~(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?example\.com/(?!$)~i';
$string = "www.example.com/example.com/http://example.com/www.abc.com/xyz.com/example.com/";
$after = preg_replace($regex_replace, '', $string);
var_dump($after);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
string(32) "www.abc.com/xyz.com/example.com/"
```

Comment: here my testing code
`$regex_replace = '~^(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?example\.com/*~i';
$string = "www.example.com/example.com/http://example.com/www.abc.com/xyz.com/example.com";
$after = preg_replace($regex_replace, '', $string);
echo $after;`

Comment: if you put '/' at end of example.com this solution fails. then it will replace the last one as well.

Comment: In that case use `$regex_replace = '~(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?example\.com/(?!$)~i';`

Comment: check for this string "http://example.com/www.abc.com/example.com/xyz.com/example.com/"
in this case it will replace middle one as well.

Comment: Did you specify your requirements clearly in your question first? You cannot keep changing your test data like this. Sorry you haven't hired me to do this job for you. My solution worked with the original problem of yours and rest you should be able to figure out.

Comment: never mind :). actually the question describes the situation. I wanted to remove only fist set of matched strings. Once there is unmatched string then after that point till end don't replace.

Answer (score -1):

Use the *`$limit`* parameter of `preg_replace` (third argument in this example):

```
preg_replace('/(http:\/\/){0,1}(www.){0,1}example.com(\/)*/i', $replacement, $subject, 1);
```

Comment: limit means only do the match X times, so he'll still have the same bug